# LINQ using join with different data type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a relationship between two tables Appointments and services, I want to view name from service table when Id(Int) equals Service column in Appointments table

```
public class Appointments
{
    public virtual Services Service { get; set; }
}

public class UsersViewModels
{
    public Services services { get; set; }
    public Appointments appointments { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
// GET
public ActionResult Index( Services services, Appointments appointments)
{
  var username = (from emp in db.Appointments
                    join w in db.Services on emp.Service equals w.Id 
                    select new UsersViewModels
                    {
                        appointments = emp,
                        services= w.UserName,
                    });
 return View(username);
}
```

View:

```
@item.appointments.Service.Name
```

How to convert Services type to Int?

Comment: You can't convert it to an int, perhaps you meant `emp.Services.Id` though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use bellow code,

compare with `emp.Service.Id equals w.Id`

```
var username = (from emp in db.Appointments
                        join w in db.Services on emp.Service.Id equals w.Id
                        select new UsersViewModels
                        {
                            appointments = emp,
                            services = w.UserName,
                        });
```

Comment: this will not work unless UsersViewModels.services and w.UserName are the same type